# Laravel 8 - Detail url is not correctly mapped

Tags: php, laravel

I am using `laravel 8` and run it on a `apache/ubuntu 20` server

My routes look like the following:

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
Route::get('/company/{symbol}', 'CompanyController@index');
```

In my `.env` file the `APP_URL` looks like the following:

`APP_URL=http://localhost/laravel_app/public`

I can reach my base url `/` the following way:

`http://localhost/laravel_app/public/`

When I go from `/` to another detail url f.ex. `/company/AAPL`, I get:

[image]

Within my base (`/`) url's blade file `index.blade.php` file the code to click the link looks like the following:

```
@foreach ($company as $i)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><a href="/company/{{$i->symbol}}">{{$i->name}} ({{$i->symbol}})</a></th>
        <td>{{$i->date}}</td>
...
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Why is the Route `/company/{symbol}` not mapped correctly?

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Using the `IndexController@index` format isn't supported out-of-the-box in Laravel 8 anymore since the `$namespace` property isn't enabled in the [RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L29) by default. Either uncomment that or use the PHP callable syntax instead `[App\Http\Controllers\IndexController::class, 'index]'. If you read the route section of the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#routing) they explain why this change was made and how to get the old behavior back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use function url it will create valid url

```
url("/company/{{$i->symbol}}")
```

route function is very help full in url creation give route name

```
Route::get('/company/{symbol}', 'CompanyController@index')->name('company.page');
```

when ever url required to print

```
route('company.page', ['symbol' => $i->symbol])
```

it will return valid url

Answer (score 1):

When you put / at the beginning of the path, it will go to root of yor project location | domain. You must set it like:

```
href="company/{{$i->symbol}}"
```

or with `url` helper

```
url('company' . $i->symbol)
```

But a better way would be naming the routes like:

```php
// add name to your route
Route::get('/company/{symbol}', 'CompanyController@index')->name('company.index');

// call the route helper to return the url
route('company.index', ['symbol' => $i->symbol]);
```